# SQL statement that shows Courses NOT taken before by Students

Tags: sql, class, having

I have three tables in MS Access database.

1. Students (Student Name, Email)

   2. Courses (Course Name, Fees)
   3. Registration (Course Name, Student Name)

I want to now create a Query that can show me all classes that each student HAS NOT taken before. This will allow my Registration Manager to pursue them to perform more class registration.

How can I easy do this in MS ACCESS? The resulting query should be:

James|Advanced Flash|
James|Advanced Editing|
Adrian|Basic Editing|
Adrian|Basic Flash|
Adrian|Advanced Flash|
Adrian|Advanced Editing|

(James have taken all 'Basic' classes where else Adrian has not taken 'Basic' and 'Advanced' classes)

Answer (score 0):

When doing this type of query, it helps to have a `driver` table that has all combinations of students and courses.  Then, join this to the registrations, and choose the rows where there is no match:

```
select driver.*
from (select s.StudentName, c.CourseName
      from Students as s,
           Courses as c
     ) as driver left join
     Registration as r
     on r.StudentName = driver.StudentName and
        r.CourseName = driver.CourseName
where r.StudentName is NULL;
```

Comment: So, i must create a new Query called [Driver], sir? Thanks for the reply very much, Gordon :)

Comment: @user2418485 . . . The driver is a subquery in the query.  I think this structure makes the logic easier to understand than other ways of formulating the query.

Comment: Gordon,.. hi. thanks for the help.
However, I tried the above, and i get a syntax error of "Syntax Error in FROM clause". Any idea why?

Comment: @user2418485 . . . Part of the reason is that MS Access does not support various SQL standard syntax.  I added `as` into the `from` clause for the aliases and changed the `left outer join` to `left join`.

Comment: So, what would i be able to do since i am using MS Access? Any idea, Gordon? Would truly appreciate a help here :) THanks much :)

Comment: @user2418485 . . . I think the revised version should work in Access.

Comment: Cna't :( too late to change version now