# How to get the missing courses for each employee in Transact SQL (SQL Server)?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I currently have the information of all the employees and the courses they've taken, what I need is to have both the data of who have taken the courses and who hasn't in Power BI. The idea is to measure how is the organization doing with the trainings and to be able to speak with bosses to arrange trainings to for the employees who haven't taken them.

This is the structure right now:

Table Employees

```
ID_Employee Names   Age  Job title                 Department   ...
1           Robert  44   Chief Procurement Officer Procurement  ...
2           James   32   Warehouse Supervisor      Operations   ...
3           Natalie 47   Sales Manager             Commercial   ...
4           John    29   Planning Executive        Operations   ...
5           Matthew 33   Finance Executive         Finance      ...
```

Table Courses

```
ID_Course Course
1         Cybersecurity
2         Effective Negotiation
3         Safety Policies
4         Performance Analysis
```

Table EmployeexCourses

```
ID_Employee ID_Course Date_Taken
1           1         20201015
1           3         20201018
2           4         20201020
3           2         20201020
3           3         20201018
4           1         20201015
```

What I'm not sure is how to proceed, I can easily get who has taken each course because that's a table itself (EmployeesxCourses) and I was using a Pivot Table to have each employee in EmployeexCourses with all the courses in columns with their dates as values. I want to use this data in Power BI, so I have a question, what should I do to have the most flexible data in Power BI? Should I do a Pivot table with all the employees and all the courses (this number is small and is fixed for a while), it'd be a 1500 rows table and there would be multiple rows with no values in the columns (employees who've not taken any course). I'm a bit confused in the how of this table with all employees, because I'd need to use 'EmployeexCourses' and 'Employees' and then turn it into a Pivot Table (I'm sure I can I just haven't done it). Or should I get a separate table for all the employees with their missing courses?

Which option is better? Or do you think of another option? I need it to be efficient and flexible in Power BI for easy use (filter by area, by course missing and such). Any idea is welcome, TIA.

Comment: Please show us the resulst that you want, as tabular text.

Comment: I don't know how to do this in Power BI so I am submitting this as a comment rather than an answer. Here is [how](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3f43e8b84058c22c5ad91f0ced99f448) to do what you are asking SQL Server based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16740861/632537) to a similar question.

Comment: @Isaac thanks a lot, that seems pretty well. Even though it doesn't include the Power BI part, seeing it already in a table cleared it pretty much for me as to how would I show it in Power BI, that's excellent, thanks!